# 12v dc motor off and on continuously

Tags: motor, dc, 12v

Hope someone can assist me here... I have a 12V DC motor that works fine when connected to a battery source, but when connecting it to a 12V 3A wall adapter, it starts and stops repeatedly.

After a lot a searching online I did figure out its because the "draw current" when starting is too high when starting the motor causing the power supply to cut out. To confirm this I also added another 12v fan in series which causes the motor to work, but of course the 12V is now being split to the motor and fan (also just a motor really) and I both dont want to run both all the time and think it might not be good to run 2 x 12v motors in series with a 12v psu - but I might be wrong - if it is safe and Im happy with the reduced speed can I run it like that?

I also seen it mighty be possible to add one or more resistors (in series) which might also fix the issue, but I have no idea which resistor to use nor how many (Im an out-of-work software developer learning electronics). Should this be the best fix, how do select the right resistors? I have tried a few already but to no avail - I suspect they might not provide enough resistance (could be too much as well - again I have no idea).

Without purchasing an expensive new PSU that can handle the current, is there another solution that someone can possible explain to me please?

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Why can't I buy bigger PSU? To be perfectly honest, I've been unemployed for 4 years. I am trying to build this (an inline duct fan) because I cannot buy it. Using parts I have lying around only. The PSU is a 12V 3.0A that I am reusing - not sure what it was originally intended for. The other questions you asked - dont have enough knowledge to answer, sorry...

Comment: How much does the motor consume? At least you should determine the current rating, by measuring it or identifying it from motor specs. You simply can't run a 4A motor with 3A supply for example so it may not be possible to run at all. At least start-up current of the motor clearly exceeds the overcurrent limit of the supply. What kind of power supply it is? Can you limit the start-up current? Can you add capacitance to provide the necessary starting current?

Comment: The motor has nothing written on it to indicate its amps - this motor I took out of an old 12V air inflator (used when camping to inflate a matress). Hope that helps?

Comment: No, it does not help. If you cannot determine how much current it needs, you can't also know if 3A power supply is enough to power it. A quick search on inflators indicated they are rated for 50W or more, meaning they consume more than 4A at 12V, which means a 3A 12V (36W) supply can't be used directly. A resitor is needed to bring current down to below 3A. Value can't be calculated. Try with 1 ohm, but if it still takes 3A, there is 3V drop over the resistor, and it needs to handle 9W. Perhaps even smaller resistance could help.

Comment: Thanks a bunch - that is a good starting point for me to try adding resistor(s). Once I tried I will post more info on the progress and hopefully also be able to close this question (thats if Im lucky enough to get it going).

Thanks again!